# How to protect/prevent/lock a Truecrypt volume (container file) against deletion , on an external HDD?

Tags: truecrypt, storage

I’ve a Truecrypt volume container file on an external HDD ,

Though Truecrypt voulmes container files are fully encrypted , they are deletable , just like normal files

I want to prevent it from getting deleted , from unauthorized users. 
How to ? 
Any solutions how ?

so nobody can delete it from my external HDD .

Sensible answers please !

Comment: Do not put it into a CT scanner for example.

Comment: @hakre CT scanner ! lol , that was kind of funny , but any sensible answers please .

Comment: Well, as long as you do not have physical control about the drive, you can not prevent deletion. Obvious that is. So what do you ask for I must ask?

Answer (score 3):

Security of TrueCrypt is against 'leakage' of data not against its loss.
For protection against loss you should backup the file or use standard OS based access control. The latter is not really an option on the external drive -- so your best bet is a backup copy (typically on the machine where you created the 'crypt' in the first place).

Comment: +1 one for the backup. What you have is what you have. What you can not trust is what you can not trust.

Answer (score 0):

Prevent it from deletion by unauthorized users by using your operating system's filesystem permissions mechanism.  You don't say what your OS is.  On UNIX-like OSes, you would do:

```
chmod 600 truecrypt-container
```

On Windows, you would right-click on the file in Explorer, choose Properties, select the Security tab, and make sure that only you (and maybe SYSTEM) have Full Control of the file and that all others have either no access or read-only access.

Of course, nothing prevents an administrator on any OS from deleting the file, regardless of how you protect it.  So be careful to whom you grant administrator access.

Comment: I'm no UNIX pro, but how can there rights work on a external drive?

Comment: True, anyone who steals the drive from the OP can mount it and delete the file.  If there's no physical security, there's no security at all.  If the OP is the only person who mounts it, then the above `chmod` command protects the file, because he is the owner of the file.  In that case, only user root can delete the file.

Comment: Mount? Or just put it under a strong electro-magnetic field? I mean I do not even need a computer to delete it nor do I need to be root. It's just simple. Probably disassembling the chassis and scratching with a screw-driver on the plates will do well as well.  But some kind of strong magnetic force should just delete that file very well on a hard disk.

Comment: Indeed.  Hence the statement: If there's no physical security, there's no security at all.

Comment: Just wanted to stress that. OP might have the wrong conception about how fragile that security model is.

Answer (score 0):

Look into file permissions in detail for your OS of choice (although I guess any admin user should be able to still take ownership of and delete the files). People can also format the drive as well, so I'm not entirely sure you can 100% protect your files on an external drives.

Comment: YUP ! Thanx for all your answers n suggestions ,

Comment: I also think that there is NO PERFECT SECURITY as such , unless u 've physical control of the drive . <1st> YUP anybody can damage a drive by a Jerk/Shock , well No need for deletion then , LOL . <2nd> Even if u set deny permissions to a file, any admin can still delete the file , using SHIFT+DELETE can delete almost any file <3rd> I think BACKUP copy is the only way out N <4rth> Keep that container file in some deep down folders , away from prying eyes , LOL. Thanx guys !